# Nextjs URL.createObjectUrl error webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Пытаюсь использовать URL.createObjectUrl в своем nextjs проекте, получаю ошибку одну единственную url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default().URL is undefined. С webpack пока особо не работал, все дефолтное. С чем это может быть связано и как исправить?